# Можно ли сказать "молоко свернулось во что-то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я исправил вопрос, поскольку изначально сформулировал его не совсем удачно. Творог я взял просто в качестве примера. Вопрос не в том, может ли молоко свёртываться именно в творог, или именно в масло, или во что-то ещё конкретное, а в том, можно ли сказать, что **молоко свернулось во что-то** (не важно, во что: в сгустки, в комки, в простоквашу, в творог и пр. - в некий продукт свёртывания молока), или так сказать нельзя, а можно только сказать, что **молоко свернулось** (просто свернулось, а не свернулось во что-то). **Молоко свернулось** - понятно, что так можно сказать. А вот **молоко свернулось в (любое название продукта свёртывания молока)** - вот так можно сказать?

P. S. Галина Аванесова сразу поняла мой вопрос совершенно правильно :)

Answer (score 2):

Молоко может "створожиться" или "свернуться" - эти выражения самодостаточны. Выражение "свернуться во что-то" обычно имеет геометрический смысл (в трубочку, в рулон, калачиком), в то время как свёртывание молока связано с изменением агрегатного состояния вещества (частичный переход из жидкой фазы в твёрдую). Хотя недопонимания такое высказывание не может вызвать, оно не добавляет подробностей и даже слегка тавтологично, поэтому стилистически небезупречно. Видимо, можно было бы оправдать авторское высказывание о свёртывании молока в творожные снежинки причудливых форм и т. п. - с геометрией нет конфликтов.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, такое употребление вряд ли можно признать корректным, поскольку "свернуться"  о продукте уже подразумевает во что-либо.

См: словарные фиксации.

СВЕРНУТЬСЯ4. Превратиться в сгусток (сгустки; о крови, белке, молоке). Молоко свернулось.

> ( Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).

Сгустившись, **превратиться в комок или комки, застыть комками** (о чем-нибудь жидком). Кровь свернулась. **Кислое молоко свернулось при кипячении.**

> (Толковый словарь Ушакова).

О жидком продукте, составе: **разделиться, выделив мелкие твёрдые части, комки.** Молоко свернулось. Кровь свернулась.

> (Толковый словарь Ожегова)

"Свернуться", как отметил Алесандр, имеет геометрический смысл.

Поэтому выражение " свернуться во что-либо является **плеоназмом** (лишние с точки зрения смысла слова и словосочетания в предложении).

Comment: По всей видимости, так оно и есть. Выражение "молоко свернулось во что-то" не является корректным по той же самой причине, по какой не является корректным выражение "вода замёрзла в лёд", поскольку "замёрзнуть" в данном случае - это уже "превратиться в лёд", и получается, как сказал Александр, явная тавтология: "вода замёрзла в лёд" = "вода превратилась в лёд в лёд".

Answer (score 1):

Молоко может только просто свернуться. Творог и масло требуют специальных действий для их приготовления, так что молоко не может "свернуться" в творог или масло.

Comment: Действительно, как же оно свернулось во что-то, если это только часть того, что было молоком; а что же тогда остальное — не молоко? Тут промежду дам пошла тема о визуальном восприятии явления. И слово "свернуться" стало выглядеть весьма бледно.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашла прецедент, в переводном романе!

Помощник, как и всегда в поисках прецедента, Гугл - Книги.

[Джулия Грегсон: Пряный аромат Востока. Переводчик: Ирина Гилярова.](https://books.google.ru/books?id=_gvzCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT552&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYzom_saDPAhULGCwKHb0PBycQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false)

> Дрожащей рукой она налила чай и протянула Виве стучавшую о блюдце
>   чашку. ***Молоко свернулось в комочки.*** – Я ненавижу буйволиное
>   молоко, – сказала она. Скучаю по настоящему чаю.

Прецедентов насчиталось: один.